# Recive location updates

Tags: android

I'm trying to write an app which will be updating infromation about current location of telephone, so i have taken code from developer android training.
http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

there is a line

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,mLocationRequest, this);
```

but i'm getting an error on this line saying

```
Error:(159, 42) java: no suitable method found for requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,com.example.gpsWakeUpper.MyActivity)
method com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; com.example.gpsWakeUpper.MyActivity cannot be converted to com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)
method com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,android.app.PendingIntent) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; com.example.gpsWakeUpper.MyActivity cannot be converted to android.app.PendingIntent)
```

My class implements such interfaces

```
public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, android.location.LocationListener
```

How can i change code so it starts working? I'm wondering why code from android site does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried to implements `com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener` instead of `android.location.LocationListener` ?

Comment: Thanks Paul, that was a big miss :-) your post helped me loads.

Answer (score 1):

That does not work because you need to have a locationListener to listen for location changes from `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates`
Ref [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderApi.html#requestLocationUpdates(com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest,%20com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener)). As per the docs to listen for location changes in your foreground activity you should pass a LocationListener or If you want to listen for changes in background you should use PendingIntent.
In your case you are passing your activity reference which does not extend any of the two required classes.
Create a new class to implements [LocationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html) or [Pending intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) depending on your requirement, and then pass it as last argument in your method call.

Comment: Your methods call matches none of the overloaded method definitions.

Comment: You are implementing the wrong LocationListener - see Paul's anser below.